# php mvc with a class for each action

Tags: php, model-view-controller

So I've been working on an PHP MVC for a client for about 3 weeks now, I've got pretty far.

I'll explain a small part of the system.

There are three types of users, `Fitters`, `Agencys`, and `Admins`.

these can all log in and have limited functionality, admin obviously has all functionality!

The admin can `add, edit and delete` `users, jobs, stock` blah blah the usual.

The way I've set it up so far is like so...

The query string is like: `/admin/users/?method=agency&action=add`

This will call the `admin` controller, and call the `users` function.

The `users` function will then call the `users` model.

The `users` model contains functionality to `add, edit, delete, admins, fitter, and agencies.`

`action=add&method=admin` will call `add_admin()` which will dynamically return a form for admins

`action=edit&method=fitter` will call `edit_fitter()` which will dynamically return a form for editting fitters

Now I was wondering...

Would it be better for me to have an `ADD` class. with ALL the add methods like, `add_fitter, add_agency, add_admin, add_job, add_stock` etc... and then have a class for `EDIT`, a class for `DELETE`, and a class for `VIEW` ???

Would this be a good way?

I thought that by doing this, I can limit the dependancy on classes like the `USERs` class.

Because the users class `adds, edits, deletes, inserts, updates and views fitters, agencies, and admins.` So the user class needs a `Validator`, a `database`, a `Form` class that returns html forms for adding and editting etc etc.

However if i had ONE class for ALL the adding, then it would eradicate the dependancy for a validator? because the add class would be responsible for returning the form. Nothing else

The reason I'm asking this question is because I'm new to MVC. and I dont want to spend the next couple of hours changing all my code, and then realising that theres a problems with my proposed pattern.

So i'm just asking you kind people, can you foresee a problem with this method?

is this how its usually done?

or is this method steered clear of for a reason?

ANY advice or tips will be GREATLY appreciated!

Just to be clear... I'm asking whether I should have separate classes for Add, Edit, Delete and view

Alex

Comment: Which you use: `/admin/users/?method=agency&action=add` or `action=add&method=admin`?

Comment: it doesnt matter which way round the query string is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just if anybody was curious, i did implement my mvc this way and it's much better!

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is store the access level of the user (session, etc), and render the page according to what was stored in the session. Urls need to be only `/admin/users/?action=add`

Or

`admin/user/edit/?id=27`

`router/controller/action/?param1=value1`